# AngularJS ng-repeat for one row in PDO fetch

Tags: php, angularjs

I am newer to Angular and seem to be having difficulty finding out why I'm getting blank fields.  I'm using the 1.7.7 version of angular-min and angular-route.

The data is being pulled from a table called "news" and I am only needing the ID and ARTICLE columns.  The ARTICLE column is stored from a CKEditor textarea.

My route looks like:

```
var app = angular.module("HabbfinityApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "home.php"
    }).when("/home", {
        redirectTo : "/"
    }).when("/news", {
        templateUrl : "news.php"
    }).when("/newsinfo/:id", {
        templateUrl : "newsinfo.php",
        controller: "newsList"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : "/"
    });
}]);
app.controller("newsList", function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.get("newsitem.php?id=" + id)
    .then(function(resp){
        $scope.item = resp;
    });
});
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

My newsitem.php looks like:

```
<?php
    require('config2.php');
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $newsQuery = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, article FROM news WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1");
    $newsQuery->execute(array(":id"=>$id));
    $newsQueryData = $newsQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($newsQueryData);
?>
```

My newsinfo.php looks like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel-default panel-custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> News</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div ng-controller="newsList">
                    <div ng-repeat="x in item">
                        <img src="assets/images/news.png" alt="News" class="img-center img-responsive">
                        <br>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https://habbfinity.ca/newsinfo/{{x.id}}&text=Take a look at this news article!" class="btn btn-info" target="_blank">Tweet</a>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <p ng-bind-html="x.article | unsafe"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ISSUE**

After the first image, twitter button and actual article, everything gets repeated another five times, so I end up with six images and six tweet buttons where the ID of the repeated five is blank.

Here's a var_dump using htmlentities so you can see exactly what those columns are pulling in.

```
string(899) "{"id":"610","article":"<p style=\"text-align:center\"><strong><span style=\"font-size:26px\">All of us at habbfinity would like wish our<\/span><\/strong><\/p>\r\n\r\n<p style=\"text-align:center\"><strong><span style=\"font-size:26px\">Builder<\/span><\/strong><\/p>\r\n\r\n<p style=\"text-align:center\"><strong><span style=\"color:#2980b9\"><span style=\"font-size:48px\">Sarah<\/span><\/span><\/strong><\/p>\r\n\r\n<p style=\"text-align:center\"><img alt=\"Image result for happy birthday gif\" src=\"http:\/\/bestanimations.com\/Holidays\/Birthday\/flowers\/happy-birthday-vintage-roses-gold-gif.gif\" \/><\/p>\r\n"}"
```

I've tried doing:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in item | limitTo: 1">
```

That doesn't work.

**TEMP FIX**

After reading through some of the posts on here, I managed a temporary fix.

I added the following to the newsList controller:

```
$scope.id = $routeParams.id;
```

I then changed newsinfo.php by moving the image and twitter button outside of ng-repeat and changed {{x.id}} in the twitter link to {{id}}.

**QUESTION**

How can I fix this to allow everything to be within the ng-repeat without having to use the temporary fix?

Or is what was done for the temporary fix the better way of doing it anyway?

**EDITED ANSWER / QUESTION**

Thanks to the suggestion below, I was able to get this resolved.

However, I have one more question.

Is there a way to do this on one page?  For example, news.php is just a list of news posts and newsinfo.php is the single news post.  Am I able to do something to get it all on news.php and keep the route to only /news, which would show the list if the route isn't news/# or show the specific item if the route is news/#?

Comment: What happens when you change `$scope.item = resp;` to `$scope.item = resp.data;`?

Comment: It actually doesn't show anything now when I added .data.  However, instead of repeating five times, it only repeated the image and twitter button twice.

Comment: Oh, right - so try to remove `ng-repeat="x in item"` and display the html using `<div ng-bind-html="item.article | unsafe"></div>` because it's a simple object, not an array. I also don't recommend wrapping WYSIWYG content with paragraph because it will make invalid HTML if it contain other paragraphs or `h1`, `ul` and so on...

Comment: This worked out perfectly, thank you!  I changed the twitter portion to {{item.id}} and that worked as well.  Would I only use the ng-repeat if I'm pulling in multiple rows from that table, such as wanting to show four of the news items?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Great, thank you again!

Comment: One other quick question.  Is there a way to do it all on one page?  News.php is just a list of news posts and newsinfo.php is that controller.  Am I able to do something to get it all on news.php and show the list if the route isn't news/#?

Comment: Anyone know if my new question is doable at all?